# Parameters between text

Tags: javascript, function

Why isn't there a way to have functions with the parameters in between text? For example:

```
function _(param1)plus(param2){
  return param1+param2;
}
```

This is just an idea I had on my mind and I didn't try anything. However, if I did this I'd get an error[image]

Comment: What is this syntax supposed to do? How is this supposed to be used? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question, but you can do this instead:

```
function plus(param1, param2){
    return param1 + param2
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Agree, this also helps with documentation and such.

Comment: yeah I know that but it's because I used scratch a lot and I could have functions like
(param)plus(param)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want this ? If you need to add text for some reason, that's what comments are for.

Having text between parameters will make code hard to read and maintain. It could even be difficult to determine what is a parameter or not. The compiler / interpreter will certainly need more time and resources to determine what's a parameter and what is just text.

Answer (score 0):

Because each programming language has its rules (syntax enforced by the parser). And a common rule for almost all languages (the same for JavaScript) is that functions can have parameters, and you specify these parameters in the brackets `()`.

So you can not continue to build function's name after the brackets, because the JavaScript will assume that everything before the brackets is the name of the function.